# How can I set a limit number of items i can have in the inventory?

Tags: javascript, lua

I have an inventory config for a game, and I would like to set a limit number for specific items, like a bread, the maximum amount of Bread I can have in the inventory is 30 for example, and if I try to buy more than that, appears a message saying it´s full.

Comment: You should specifiy what specifically you are stuck with, is it the printing of the message? is it the limiting of the items?

Comment: what is your question about? Lua or javascript?  show a [mcve] and read [ask] what would you do in real life? you would look how many items you have and if you have reached the limit you would deny buying more. so you need an item count, a maximum item count, relational operators and some conditional statement

Comment: Basically the system of the inventory is by Weight, but I want to turn it into a Limit System like this for example if inventoryItem.amount <= item.limit then
-- Give Item
end

Comment: Here´s the project link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b4320859d516c6d6f09b1671736f5aa20210124144344/98ef12

Comment: edit your question and add all relevant information (code) in there. I will certainly not click some random download link. what stops you from solving your problem?

Comment: Can't  you just give each item a weight of 1, and then the weight limit is the same as the number of items limit.